# Update Stripe Customer from Firebase Function (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, firebase, stripe-payments

I have the following Firebase Function:

```
exports.updateStripeCustomer = functions.region('europe-west3')
    .firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onUpdate( async (change, context) => {
        const oldValue = change.before.data();
        const newValue = change.after.data();
        
        if( JSON.stringify(newValue.adresse) != JSON.stringify(oldValue.adresse) ) {
            const user = await admin.auth().getUser(change.after.id)
            .then((user) => {
                return user.displayName
            })
            const stripe = Stripe(<api-key>)
            const customer = await stripe.customers.update(oldValue.stripe_id,
                {
                    shipping: {
                        address: {
                            city: newValue.ort,
                            postal_code: newValue.plz,
                            line1: newValue.strasse,
                            line2: newValue.hausnum
                        },
                        name: user
                    },
                }
            );
            return customer
        }
        return 'no Data changed'
})
```

The function itself works - only the format for passing the shipping information is not clear to me and seems wrong. The example from the Stripe Api documentation is not quite clear to me.

Stripe return the following error:

```
parameter_unknown - shipping[0]
Received unknown parameter: shipping[0]
```

Complete LOG Error:

```
{
  "shipping": {
    "0": {
      "name": "Testi Tester"
    }
  }
}
-------------
Response-Text
{
  "error": {
    "code": "parameter_unknown",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-unknown",
    "message": "Received unknown parameter: shipping[0]",
    "param": "shipping[0]",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

Many Thanks for Help !

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters appear to conform to the API docs for `shipping` ([link](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-shipping)). The error structure suggests that your `shipping` object is being interpreted as an array, which means something isn't being stringified properly for the request.

My hunch that that this is related to your `name: user` child parameter. This should just be a string, but based on the line `user.displayName` earlier in your snippet it appears `user` is a complex object. Did you mean to use the same `user.displayName` in the update request?

I'd suggest you try putting in a temporary test value `name: 'test name'` to see if that resolves the issue, then figure out which attribute from your `user` object you want to use.

Comment: Hi Nolan, thanks for your answer and the thought process ;)
The variable user.displayName returns a string (from the Firebase User Object). If I omit the shipping object, name is also interpreted (output) correctly
My guess is that the shipping object/array is not formatted correctly. But I haven't found a correct solution/formatting yet either.

Comment: Unfortunately, exactly the example from the link with Metadata is not correct in this case :(

Comment: Have you checked your developer logs to see how Stripe is receiving this request? It might help to illuminate what is not working. https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/ Go there and look for your error on customer update, check what payload Stripe received and share that in your question.

Comment: Yep always checked...Have Edit the Originals Post

Comment: Something is causing that to be interpreted as an array, which doesn't make much sense. If you hardcode test address fields too, does this change? Beyond that, you may want to write in to Stripe support to get help.

Comment: Thx, Nolan - I will try the Harcoded Variant - tomorrow I write to the Support